# matching words in a string in order with php or js/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, compare, match

i have a program to test candidates typing speed. they basicly follow string for 3 mins. after 3 mins i piece string into array in php and compare by order.

this code have serial errors like;
1- when candidates jumps between rows like up and down order confuses in algorithm and miscalculates matching words.
2- in one session we have 100 candidates typing. it means my wampserver will take 100 requests to compare huge strings at the same time. it causes to not respond to some candidates. that'll take us to re test these candidates since we couldn't get results from wampserver.

since i need to keep results in mysql, i'm thinking of loading calculate jobs to javascript in their browser and only send results to wampserver to write these down to mysql.

i'm searching alternative ways to solve these problems for 5 months at least and here i'm open to any kind of suggestions.

should i make calculations at javascript by spliting string into words to array and compare?
or should i keep it in php wampserver but how to solve these kind of instant 100 requests run smoothly.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably write a javascript version of the typing speed algorithm and then save the results to mysql via ajax

Comment: so is there any way to match words in order and count correct (matching) ones beside spliting whole string into array and check it word by word?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example on how to compare 2 arrays

```js
var arr1 = 'This is an example'.split(' ');
var arr2 = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'example'];

for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++)
  if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i])
    console.log(arr1[i], 'Didnt match at index', i);
```